# OpenTok Sdk Error iOS

Tags: ios, cocoapods, opentok

I am integrating OpenTok in iOS project (objective-C).I am using Xcode 8. My deployment target is 9.0. I have installed OpenTok 2.10.0 through Cocoapods. Now I have implemented all the delegate methods required in my `UIViewController`. But when I compile the code it show me errors. Please help my out.
[image]

Comment: try to run with your devices

Comment: This is a linker error that is caused by the framework being not linked with the application binary. If you are using cocoapods, are you using the .xcworkspace or the .xcodeproj?